# django rest framework same route, different

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

i'm using django rest framework to build an api, here is my problem

```
url(r'^profiles/(?P<pk>[0-9]*)', ProfileRetrieveView.as_view(), name='profiles-detail'),
url(r'^profiles/(?P<pk>[0-9]*)', ProfileUpdateView.as_view(), name='profiles-update'),
```

---

```
    class ProfileRetrieveView(RetrieveAPIView):

    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

class ProfileUpdateView(UpdateAPIView):

    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
```

When i query the api with the link /profile/2 and the method patch, i receive 405, method not allowed, only the get method is allowed, how can i solve that without haven to transform my two view classes into on class with a GenericView Base class and Retrive + update Mixins.

Comment: this is how URL matching works... it goes down the list and chooses the first one that matches.  The correct way to do this is to have one class handle it. But in the router config, if I recall correctly, you can route different methods to different classes, but you need to URL match once.

Answer (score 1):

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^profiles/(?P<pk>[0-9]*)', ProfileRetrieveUpdateView.as_view(), name='profiles-detail-update'),
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveUpdateAPIView

class ProfileRetrieveUpdateView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):

    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method == "GET":
            return []
        else:
            return [IsAuthenticated()]
```

Comment: No details, No reference, nothing? really is this an answer or just a bunch of code. I mean why you did not provide any technical description about why is this happening? Please update your answer and add some details about the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should condense this into a single endpoint. You can have a single class handle all the listing, update, get, etc for this. Try...something like this:

```
from rest_framework import mixins, viewsets
class ProfileUpdateView(viewset.ModelViewSet,
                        mixins.ListModelMixin,
                        mixins.UpdateModelMixin):

    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

    get_queryset(self):
          return Profile.objects.all()
```

If you're using pure models, use the built in model stuff, and check out the mixins. It will save you TONS of generic code writing. It has some magic that knows how to route the request to the matching http method.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#mixins

Answer (score 0):

Django rest framework provides generic view you don't require Mixins.
You can directly use `RetrieveUpdateAPIView`. Provides request methods `get` to retrieve data, `put` update data and `patch` for partial update.

```
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveUpdateAPIView

class ProfileUpdateView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
```

Reference: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveupdateapiview